# handling dataset array as dataset in matlab like as other programs(spss,r,stata)

Tags: matlab, dataset, statistics

i have a table that has 80 variables, 512 observations

and all values are numeric

i want to factor analysis with my table(class:dataset) as dataset.

still now, i am using this expression to do that

```
factoran(double(table),m)
```

I want to use an expression with datasetfun like this for conserving table information.

```
datasetfun(@(x) factoran(x,m), table, 'datasetoutput', true)
```

but it is not working.

```
Error using factoran (line 133)
X must have more than one row (observation) and more than one column (variable).

Error in @(x)factoran(x,3)


Error in dataset/datasetfun (line 101)
```

how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b = datasetfun(fun,A)` applies the function specified by `fun` to **each variable** (each column) of the dataset array `A`. As `factoran` needs more than one column to perform its opertaions, it can't be used with `datasetfun`.